# Swift 5 Activity Indicator not showing

Tags: swift, uiactivityindicatorview, activity-indicator

I have checked other questions/answers, yet not one of them is working for me.

I have many view controllers that load the data from the database during segue preparation. Therefore, I have put the activity indicator as follows:

func tableView/collectionView (didSelectRow/item){
       ...

```
self.showSpinner()
self.performSegue(...) -> prepare(for segue...)  : data gets loaded
self.removeSpinner()
```

}

with functions defined in

```
import UIKit

var aView : UIView?

extension UIViewController{

    func showSpinner(){
        aView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        aView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)

        let ai = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .large)
        ai.center = aView!.center
        ai.color = .red
        ai.startAnimating()
        aView?.addSubview(ai)
        self.view.addSubview(aView!)

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 20, repeats: false, block: {_ in self.removeSpinner()})
    }

    func removeSpinner(){

        aView?.removeFromSuperview()
        aView = nil
    }
}
```

the code gets executed (I checked it), yet there is no sign of the spinner or the view with a darker background.

Even in I define

```
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
```

and put

```
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
performSegue...
activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
```

nothing happens. There are no new elements (expected: view with activity indicator or just the activity indicator) in the view hierarchy.
What's wrong?

UPDATE:

if I call it in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
        self.showSpinner()  //show indicator
        return indexPath
```

all the code (willSelect, DidSelect, Segue) gets executed, and only then for 1/10 sec do I see the spinner while transitioning to the next view.
I need, however, that the spinner gets shown BEFORE the further code of DidSelect gets executed

Comment: On which view controller's view are you adding the activity indicator?

Comment: on self.view (self is viewController)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  Bear Cahill from Accelebrate! Here is the solution:

> The problem was it was told to show the spinner and perform the segue. It
>   doesn't do that until the function ends. Once the function ends it
>   does both of those so not until it's performing the segue does the
>   spinner show. You know it's showing b/c when you go back, it's there.
>   So you need to call show spinner and allow control to go back to the
>   run loop (let the function finish) and THEN call perform segue to load
>   data, etc. I'd recommend maybe using a Timer: so you'd call
>   showSpinner, then start a timer and in the body of the timer, call the
>   perform segue. That way the function will end, the spinner will show
>   and then perform segue will get called. Just have the timer set for
>   like 0.01 seconds.